# How to add "Yes" and "No" options to auto-close AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, dialog

There's first time for everything I guess.  This is my 1st question here.

I am developing a car application, where I need to minimise user interaction while driving.  The app needs to suggest from time to time to the user a "decision" it has made.  Let's call this "GREEN".  Then the application displays an `AlertDialog`, telling the user of the decision, and lets the user either:

- wait for 3 seconds, after which the Dialog disappears and "GREEN" is
  enforced
- press "RED" button on the Dialog, which changes this decision
  into "RED" instead

I am trying to implement with an `AlertDialog` plus a `Timer`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Seems it was GREEN");
builder.setMessage("You can change it to RED by pressing a button");
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setPositiveButton("RED!", new DialogInterface.OnCLickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) [
        // 1. Do things required by RED option
    }
} 

final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();

dlg.show();

final Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        // 2. Do things required by GREEN option
        dlg.dismiss(); 
        t.cancel();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Problem is, after 1., 2. is always executed, so if the user tries to "cancel" the "GREEN" by pushing the "RED" button, the "GREEN" option is still run after the "RED" one.

How could I make this exclusive, so when the app informs of a decision via a dialog, waits for a few seconds, and if the user didn't opt for the other one, enforce this decision?

Comment: you need to cancel your timer when you click the button

Comment: Care to tell how to do this exactly, in my example code?

Comment: t.cancel(); cancels the timer. you need to do that when you click the red button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cancel your timer-

```
builder.setPositiveButton("RED!", new DialogInterface.OnCLickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
    {
        if(t != null)
        {
            t.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```